# How do i make XML from a List?

Tags: c#, xml

Assume i have the class

```
public class Test1
{
    public int BINID { get; set; }
    public int NUMBER1 { get; set; }
    public decimal HOLGRAPHIC { get; set; }

    public Test1(int id, int num, decimal hol)
    {
        BINID = id;
        NUMBER1 = num;
        HOLGRAPHIC = hol;
    }
}
```

Assume i have created a List collection of Test1 in another class called `Test2`. In `Test2` class i have created the collection t of `Test1`.

```
List<Test1> t = new List<Test1>();
```

Assume this List contains two `Test1` objects. How do i convert the List to `XML` to have the following schema?

```
<t>
<Test1>
  <BINID>23</BINID>
  <NUMBER1>123</NUMBER1>
  <HOLOGRAPHIC>2345.12</HOLOGRAPHIC>
</Test1>
<Test1>
  <BINID>3</BINID>
  <NUMBER1>346233</NUMBER1>
  <HOLOGRAPHIC>12.345</HOLOGRAPHIC>
</Test1>
</t>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to generate the XML. Using the classes XElement and XAttribute, you can generate the XML file corresponding to the schema required.

Please refer this link for an example.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=428

Something like :

```
var xEle = new XElement("t",
                from ele in t
                select new XElement("test1",
                             new XElement("BINID", ele.ID),
                               new XElement("NUMBER1", ele.Number1),
                               new XElement("HOLOGRAPHIC", ele.Holigraphic)
                           ));

    xEle.Save("D:\\yourFile.xml");
    Console.WriteLine("Converted to XML");
```